# Unable to find an entry point named 'MediaInfo_New' in DLL 'MediaInfo.dll'

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, nancy, mediainfo

I am using MediaInfoDotNet library which internally called C++ MediaInfo.dll.

This has been running on PROD fine for a while. However suddenly this morning it started throwing below error:

```
Unable to find an entry point named 'MediaInfo_New' in DLL 'MediaInfo.dll'
```

No publish has been made to PROD, so as far as I am concerned nothing changes there.

Just for a context this is an ASP.Net Nancy app running on Azure AppService.

Now few hours later, after unable to find any explanation we just restarted the server and the problem go away.

Anyone has idea why and how it happened? I can't afford to have this kind of errors happening on PROD again.

Comment: I'm having the same problem on my PROD webservice with a self-written C++ DLL. Any updates?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to get ride of outdated "DotNet" thing, and use MediaInfo library directly, there is a C# binding.
Download the "DLL without installer" package, it contains a C# project file.
https://mediaarea.net/fr/MediaInfo/Download/Windows